# Note 9 Clock App - change timezone to no timezone

Tags: clock, samsung-galaxy-note-9

I have a note 9.  I used clock app for my alarms.  I can not change the timezone from central.  I live somewhere we do not have a timezone.  We do not change our clocks.  No matter what I do, the wrong time shows at the top of my screen.  My service provider displays the correct time below that, but this messes with my alarms and locks screens.  HOW do I fix this? I have tried several "fixes" for android clock app but it would seem my note 9 is different as I can't find instructions that will work with my phone.

Comment: Have you tried updating the timezone from your system settings? Settings > general > date and time

Comment: What do you mean by "we do not have a timezone"? Everybody has a timezone.